# Имитатор систем

Tags: c++, gpss

Требуется написать программу имитатор систем. Т.е. задаются параметры сети в консольном варианте вопросами пользователю: сколько узлов? какой первый узел? ... Затем собранные сведения генерируются в текст модели на языке GPSS и запускается модель. Может кто делал что-либо похожее или может помочь написать программу или идеи есть какие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GPSS` - язык скорее мертвый, нежели живой, и готовой библиотеки / транслятора для `C++` вы не найдете, т.е все придется, к сожалению, реализовывать самостоятельно.

---

Поскольку ваша финальная программа - это, скорее, простенький шаблонизатор, нежели полноценный транслятор *(если я правильно понял, то в описываемой системе не так уж много переменных параметров и, следовательно, финальный результат на `GPSS` будет удовлетворять некоторым паттернам),* то весь вопрос заключается лишь в том, **как правильно наладить взаимодействие** уже известного шаблона для `GPSS` системы и как вставить в него данные, введенные пользователем.

Дальше уже все зависит от вашей фантазии - шаблон можно организовать как `xml`-файл с вставками `GPSS` кода, можно придумать свой тривиальный формат для его хранения, можно упороться и воспользоваться чем-нибудь тяжелым вроде `boost::spirit` и уже перейти напрямую к грамматикам.

*Парсинг в таком случае напрямую зависит от тех параметров, которые задаются в шаблоне и, в принципе, не должен быть сложным в реализации.*